# d3 dulplicate graph when updating data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js

I wanted to update my d3 graph when user select the site. But when I select the dropdown menu up top, I get new graph being generated and I cannot seem to find a way to remove it.

[image]

this is the code in `<script>`

```
<script>

import * as d3 from 'd3'
import { rgbaToHex } from '../utils/color.ts'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      selectedSite: '',
      selectedWhale: '',
      groupType: '',
      heatmapShow: false
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.generateChart()
  },
  methods: {
    generateChart () {
      // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
      const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 30 }
      const width = 1850 - margin.left - margin.right
      const height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom

      // make the area for the graph to stay
      const svg = d3.select('#heatmap')
        .append('svg') // svg area can include headers and color scales
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right) // set width
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom) // set height
        .append('g') // new g tag area for graph only
        .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.bottom})`)
        // stick g tag to the bottom
      const xLabel = d3.range(259)
      const yLabel = d3.range(23, -1, -1)

      const x = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(xLabel)
        .range([0, width])
        .padding(0.05)

      svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickValues(x.domain().filter((_, i) => !(i % 6))))

      const y = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(yLabel)
        .range([height, 0])
        .padding(0.05)

      svg.append('g').call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickValues(y.domain().filter((_, i) => !(i % 5))))

      d3.json('../predictions.json').then((data) => {
        const u = svg.selectAll().data(data.heatmaps[this.selectedWhale][this.selectedSite])

        u.exit().remove()

        const uEnter = u.enter().append('rect')

        uEnter
          .merge(u)
          .transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .attr('x', function (d) {
            return x(d[1]) // return cell's position
          })
          .attr('y', function (d) {
            return y(d[0])
          })
          .attr('cx', 1)
          .attr('cy', 1)
          .attr('width', x.bandwidth()) // return cell's width
          .attr('height', y.bandwidth()) // return cell's height
          .style('fill', function (d) {
            return rgbaToHex(0, 128, 255, 100 * d[2])
          })
          .on('mouseover', function () { // box stroke when hover
            d3.select(this)
              .style('stroke', 'black')
              .style('opacity', 1)
          })
          .on('mouseout', function () { // fade block stroke when mouse leave the cell
            d3.select(this)
              .style('stroke', 'none')
              .style('opacity', 0.8)
          })
          .on('click', (d) => {
            console.log(d)
            this.heatmapShow = true
          })

        uEnter.exit().remove()
      })
    }
  },
  watch: {
    selectedSite: function () {
      this.generateChart()
    },
    selectedWhale: function () {
      this.generateChart()
    },
    groupType: function (value) {
      console.log(value)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I've done to fix it was, as was suggested before, just add `d3.select('svg').remove()` before I start creating the svg const again.

```
      const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 30 }
      const width = 1850 - margin.left - margin.right
      const height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom

      d3.select('svg').remove()

      // make the area for the graph to stay
      const svg = d3.select('#heatmap')
        .append('svg') // svg area can include headers and color scales

      /* rest of the code */
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you're selecting the ID to paint your graph canvas into it but you append it instead of inserting a new one.

> ## selection.append(type)
>
> If the specified type is a string, appends a new element of this type (tag name) as the last child of each selected element, or before the next following sibling in the update selection if this is an enter selection.

More on he subject is written [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v1.4.1/README.md#selection_append).

Try removing the ID before repainting it with [selection remove](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v1.4.1/README.md#selection_remove) and then try to append/insert again